# Does any of the following sound metaphorically correct?

Tags: phrases, expressions, prepositions, colloquialisms, metaphors

"This data has been sitting on my hard drive for years."
OR
"This data has been sitting in my hard drive for years."

Comment: This data? Oh dear.

Comment: @David Is that wrong??

Comment: Data is plural. The singular is datum. Admittedly this is pedantic, and the word is commonly used in the singular, but if you read the description of the purpose of the site, I would find this sort of question on preference for prepositions in a technical context inappropriate.

Comment: @Levi [Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/data) definition of *data* says that is both singular and plural, and [Oxford (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/data) says that it's a mass noun. So, unless you are writing for a technical publication with a style guide that says to only use *data* in the plural, there is nothing wrong with using *data* in the singular. Especially in non-technical contexts, *these data*, while correct, no longer sounds as idiomatic as *this data*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google Ngram Viewer, data is never **in** a hard drive, but always **on** a hard drive.

Comparing *data on the hard drive* to *data in the hard drive*, [Google shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=data%20on%20the%20hard%20drive%2Cdata%20in%20the%20hard%20drive&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdata%20on%20the%20hard%20drive%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdata%20on%20the%20hard%20drive%3B%2Cc0) that (at least in print), *on* is quite common, but *in* doesn't exist at all:

[image: data in or on the hard drive]

This result matches my own impression from my years in IT. Almost nobody ever says that data is *in* a hard drive.

---

As for the verb, although *sitting* would be understood, and I see nothing wrong with it informally, if you want to use the verb that's most common, simply used *stored*.

Again per [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=data%20stored%20on%2Cdata%20sitting%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdata%20stored%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdata%20sitting%20on%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdata%20stored%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdata%20sitting%20on%3B%2Cc0), *stored* is far more common:

[image: data stored on versus data sitting on]

---

In conclusion, the most common of phrases would be the following:

> This data has been **stored on** my hard drive for years.

Comment: 'Sitting on' is far from rigorously synonymous with 'stored on'; the 'lying around idly' implications are far stronger. I'd stick with 'sitting on' here. But +1 for the research and a better answer than the one accepted.

Answer (score -1):

"In" and "on" seem both acceptable; I'd choose "in" however as I picture the relationship of data to repository as a containing one where the bits are actually part of the physical structure of the disk. As for "sitting" there is nothing metaphorical about it since it has come to mean "to be in a particular place" ([OALD, 3](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/sit?q=sit)).

Comment: Thank you. But is it correct to use "sitting" at all? Does that sound like something a native would say?

Comment: @Levi It is not a verb I'd use, personally, as I have a certain aversion for changing the fundamental meaning of words to make them say something else than what they've initially been construed to express, but it is nevertheless a common practice to assign meanings that way, in all language, and we have to live with it. According to the the dictionary, I must conclude that this usage is native of English; nevertheless, I couldn't say that all speakers of English have a neutral attitude towards it; some of them might share my point of view.

Comment: I don't know what I would do without your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: 'There is nothing metaphorical about it' is incorrect. The prototypical meaning involves buttocks; the fact that dictionaries now often list common metaphorical extensions, as here, does not mean that metaphorical extensions no longer involve metaphor. That's not how the overarching term is used. A dead metaphor still involves metaphor / metaphorical broadening of the original usage. // And as @Jason's **research** indicates, the surface (on) rather than the container metaphor for hard drives is idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree that in the derivation of the meaning, there is a metaphorical process, but in the use of the derived term, which has acquired a well established new meaning, there is no metaphorical use of a term, not even a figurative one and just a plain literal meaning. I don't think we have to go into the process of derivation here, that is not the point.

Comment: It's rather precious (I could think of other descriptors) to arrogate 'As for "sitting" there is nothing metaphorical about it' and then attempt to deflect arguments by 'I don't think we have to go into the process of derivation here, that is not the point.'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I do not attempt to deflect the argument since in "sitting" sounding metaphorically correct or not there is no metaphor and only the plain literal sense of "to sit", which is "to be in some place", acknowledging the added connotation the dictionary apparently fails to capture and that you point out.

Comment: Lacking relevant (and this does not include selected definitions from books not properly dealing with such concepts) substantiating evidence. For example, **look forward to** [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/look_forward_to)]: Await eagerly. // Whereas, from an article titled [_Metaphor_ written by @John Lawler](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf): << TIME is SPACE: A metaphor theme that licenses English speakers to refer to temporal phenomena with words and expressions defined in terms of (their experience of linear motion in) space. ... **look forward to it** >>.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree with that: "forward" is not defined relatively to time and  it is here used metaphorically in a reference to time; however in "sitting on the disk" there is no "tampering" with definitions; that is about all that we should be concerned with in connection with the question;  a metaphorical definition and a metaphorical use by a writer should be kept as two separate notions even if there is much they have in common. Not everyone will agree to use someone else's metaphors, (1/2)

Comment: The metaphorical usages of prepositions has been dealt with on ELU before. The literal, prototypical usages are spatial and/or temporal (on the table), then transparent metaphor (on the train), then semi-opaque (on television / on the hard drive), then opaque (on fire). Literal ends at prototypical, no matter how many dictionaries include definitions to handle metaphorical usages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  perhaps not finding them necessarily proper, but there is no question for any one about accepting metaphorical definitions; everyone has to agree with what is being inferred whereas in the case of a metaphorical use the writing is open to criticism. (2/2)