# Meaning of 'war was brewing in'

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

I am studying a book and there is a sentence: "By early fall, ***war was brewing*** in Iraq."

What does brew mean in this context? I thought 'brew' could only be associated with a beverage.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary should give you the various definitions.

Brewing is that process through which by means of heating up a substance immersed into a liquid that liquid becomes a solution of that substance in the liquid (beer, coffee, tea, etc.); this concept has given rise to the metaphorical definition of the verb "to brew (up)" used only in the continuous tenses ([OALD, 4](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/brew_1?q=brew)).

As the substance progressively adulterates the liquid and turns it into something else, the belligerent trends in the societies adulterate the ways of thinking and turn them into ways of thinking receptive to the idea of war.

Comment: I suspect that brew has migrated from being used as a metaphor to having its own meaning to contrive, bring about, foment.  Any comments on this are welcome.

Comment: The earliest I can find is "mischief is brewing"   from the late 1700s ---https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mischief+is+brewing&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1790&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmischief%20is%20brewing%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmischief%20is%20brewing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMischief%20is%20brewing%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cmischief%20is%20brewing%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmischief%20is%20brewing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMischief%20is%20brewing%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @BruceMurray That's clear from the entry "brew" in OALD; "to brew (up)" is a verb in its own right that is used, not for pleasant and concrete concepts (beer, coffee, tea, etc.) but often unpleasant ones -- of possibly a rather abstract nature -- (war, storms, popular discontent, social change, etc.), the physical process associated with the plain acception of the verbal form being several transformed, analogous, notions on many possible levels: animal minds, human minds, meteorological conditions, elements of scientific progress, economis conditions, etc.

Comment: @Bruce Murray Here's a view contrary to '_brew_ has ceased to be non-literal in these broadened usages': [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of ... Idioms ...2002](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/brewing): 'brew a plot' 
Fig. to plot something; to make a plot. _The children brewed an evil plot_..
 //

Comment: 'brew something up'  
1. Lit. to brew something, as in making coffee or tea. ...
2. Fig. to cause something to happen; to foment something. _I could see that they were brewing some kind of trouble up._ 'brew up'
Fig. to build up; [for something] to begin to build and grow. (Typically said of a storm.) A bad storm is brewing up in the west. Something serious is brewing up ...' And if these usages are figurative, they are metaphorical.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Figurative language is the more general term. Metaphorical can be used in exactly the same way. (owlman, 3rd post: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/figurative-vs-metaphorical.1916887/). It seems to me that there are two meanings involved: this figurative one you are introducing involves a subject that is not the recipient of the action and the verb is transitive whereas in the case of the verb discussed in the OP's question, the subject is the recipient of the action and the verb is intransitive.The meanings do differ : concoct vs. to be in fermentation.

Comment: Would those ELU users giving negative votes be cooperative enough and tell us what they reproach the answer with?

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to read the question I asked on whether or not  once a non-prototypical sense for a word/expression has been admitted into a dictionary that sense should not subsequently be labelled 'metaphorical'. [Has a _dead metaphor_ ceased to be a _metaphor_?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174573/has-a-dead-metaphor-ceased-to-be-a-metaphor) Nobody came up with a convincing resolution (in fact, the different schools obviously still exist. But they should for the present always be recognised as being different interpretations.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That is in fact a question that opens new vistas to me relative to the initial point of view I shared with you recently on the occasion of some other question, this tentative point of view being (roughly) that metaphor is a prime mover in the way of ending up with a definition. It is an interesting question and I might try to provide some answer to it in days to come.